# Call to undefined function toArray() in tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to test my model and see the result in Laravel with Tinker:

When I use toArray() method I see this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function toArray() in eval()'d code
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What exactly is your code that you are executing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will executed exactly the same in "standard" Laravel and in the tinker.

You must be using toArray() on some object that does not have this function defined.

toArray() will work for example on Eloquent models and on Collections.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel5 toArray() method doesn't exist in model classes. i use get(); method and it work for me.